How to change this default green color to custom hero image in Docusaurus?
I'm trying to change the default green color in homepage with my custom hero image but its showing only the half of image
This is homepage image
here's the important code snippet
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Link from '@docusaurus/Link';
import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';
import Layout from '@theme/Layout';
import HomepageFeatures from '@site/src/components/HomepageFeatures';
import Heading from '@theme/Heading';
import styles from './index.module.css';
import React from 'react';

function HomepageHeader() {
  const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
  return (
<header className={clsx('hero hero--primary', styles.heroBanner)} style={{backgroundImage: `url('/img/hero.jpeg')`}}>
      <div className="container">
        <Heading as="h1" className="hero__title">
          {siteConfig.title}
        </Heading>
        <p className="hero__subtitle">{siteConfig.tagline}</p>
        <div className={styles.buttons}>
          <Link
            className="button button--secondary button--lg"
            to="/docs/intro">
           Know More!⏱️
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default function Home(): JSX.Element {
  const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
  return (
    <Layout
      title={`Hello from ${siteConfig.title}`}
      description="Description will go into a meta tag in <head />">
      <HomepageHeader />
      <main>
        <HomepageFeatures />
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
}

and css is
/* src/pages/index.module.css */

.heroBanner {
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 6rem 0; /* Adjust padding as needed */
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 996px) {
  .heroBanner {
    padding: 3rem 0; /* Adjust padding for smaller screens */
  }
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


i'm aware of the fact that there is similar question in this site but that does not answer my problem.
I've tried to check developer tool to see margin etc but it's not helping

I was able to set image using docusaurus official codesandbox. I just opened devtools and set background image with random image url from internet. It worked as expected: whole hero section has an image background. Are you sure your image has proper sizes?
